# Function template accepting only non integral types (specifially bidirectional iterators)

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, c++98

I need a function template that only accepts non-integral types, if the arguments are iterators i made (i made my own class and using enable_if and a tag i manage to deduce whether or not the params are the iterators I created or not)

```
template <typename InputIterator>
        foo (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type(),
        typename ft::enable_if<InputIterator::InputIter, InputIterator>::type = NULL)
        {
            insert(begin(), first, last);
        }
```

I want to make sure the parameters passed to the function are either my own iterator or a bidirectional iterator, however i thought this would be much easier if i could just check if the "InputIterator"  is simply non integral but i dont know what is needed precisely to implement it, and am not sure if its a good idea since at the end of the day, what i really need is to make sure its an iterator that fits my criterias.

How should i proceed ? what functions are worth looking into ?

am using -std=c++98, so am sticking to the c++98 libraries, so no c++11 or any functionality that came out after 98.

Comment: Maybe remove SFINAE altogether? Why do you need it in the first place, if approximating "bidirectional iterator" as "non-integral" acceptable to you? *"am using -std=c++98"* :/ You really should upgrade. Even `std::is_integral` is a C++11 feature.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat its part of a school project, am limited to c++ 98 due to the subject, I remade my own enable_if and is_integral but i was just lacking knowledge in areas i couldn't pinpoint to make the rest of the function, some answers mentionned a lot of stuff i didnt know before and it looks quite helpful so i think it's doable on 98, I will try to implement what i learn and if it works ill share the solution (in case someone has a similar issue one day)

Comment: "part of a school project". Then you are *probably* overthinking it. "Use C++98" and "remake parts of C++>=11" are two requirements that hardly ever go together in such projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are limited to C++98 it is best to try animate SFINAE tools available in later versions `c++03`. This way code will be more familiar for future maintainer.

For example C++98 do not have following tools: `std::enable_if`, `std::iterator_traits` `std::is_integral`.

Your case is quite simple, so it is not hard, but lots of boiler plate is needed:

```cpp
#include <numeric>

template <typename T>
struct is_integer {
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <>
struct is_integer<int> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

template <>
struct is_integer<char> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

template <>
struct is_integer<long int> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

template <>
struct is_integer<unsigned int> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

template <>
struct is_integer<unsigned char> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

template <>
struct is_integer<unsigned long int> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

template <bool codition, typename T = void>
struct enable_if {};

template <typename T>
struct enable_if<true, T> {
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
struct iterator_traits {
    typedef typename T::value_type value_type;
};

template <typename T>
struct iterator_traits<T*> {
    typedef T value_type;
};

template <typename InputIterator>
typename enable_if<
        is_integer<
                typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type
            >::value,
        typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type
    >::type
foo(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
    typedef typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type type;
    return std::accumulate(first, last, type(0));
}

void test() {
    int arr[3] = {1, 3, 4};
    foo(arr, arr + 3);
}

#ifdef TEST_FAILURE
void test_faiure() {
    double arr[3] = {1, 3, 4};
    foo(arr, arr + 3);
}
#endif
```

[live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f4jvoKb5E) [small improvment](https://godbolt.org/z/cdTedrq34)

I didn't check what was the status of boost for C++98 (especially that you didn't specified compiler), but you should check if this is already done there and if it could be used by your compiler.

Comment: I think `iterator_traits` are in C++98. Here's [your code](https://godbolt.org/z/Es6nWbjPf) using `std::iterator_traits` instead.

Comment: @TedLyngmo that is cool. I had to mess up something when verifying code and failed to find proper documentation for C++98.

Answer (score 1):

You can create some type traits yourself to get SFINAE.

Since it's C++98, you can start by creating some traits that are included in the newer standards:

```
template<class T, class U>
struct is_same { static const bool value; };
template<class T, class U> const bool is_same<T,U>::value = false;
 
template<class T>
struct is_same<T, T> { static const bool value; };
template<class T> const bool is_same<T,T>::value = true;

template<bool B, class T = void> struct enable_if {};
 
template<class T> struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

You can then build your own trait:

```
template<class It>
struct accepted_iterator {
    static const bool value;
};

#include <iterator>
template<class It>
const bool accepted_iterator<It>::value = // add the accepted iterator categories here:
    is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category,
                   std::bidirectional_iterator_tag>::value ||
    is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category,
                   std::random_access_iterator_tag>::value;
```

And checking the iterator type, SFINAE style:

```
template <typename InputIterator>
typename enable_if<accepted_iterator<InputIterator>::value>::type
foo (InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {

}
```